# Overlaying boxplot with a lineplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some fake data representing the answering times of different users answering an online survey.
The dataset has three variables: the id of the respondent (user), the name of the question (question) and the answering time for each question (time).

```r
n <- 1000
dat <- data.frame(user = 1:n, 
                  question = sample(paste("q", 1:4, sep = ""), size = n, replace = TRUE),
                  time = round(rnorm(n, mean = 10, sd=4), 0)
                  )

pltSingleRespondent <- function(df, highlightUsers){
  dat %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = question, y = time)) + 
    geom_boxplot(fill = 'orange') + coord_flip() +
    ggtitle("Answering time per question")
}


pltSingleRespondent(dat, c(1, 31) )
```

I was creating a function that plots a boxplot with the answering times for each question. However, now I'd like to overlay that plot with the answering times of specific respondents (highlightUsers). The following image shows an example:

[image: Text]

Can someone please explain me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most direct way to do this is to subset your data within a call to `geom_line`.

I'll start with a different set of random data, since the sample data in the question does not include all questions for a user.

```r
set.seed(2021)
dat <- expand.grid(user = factor(1:50), question = paste0("q", 1:4))
dat$time <- round(rnorm(200, mean = 10, sd = 4), 0)

dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = question, y = time)) + 
  geom_boxplot(fill = 'orange') + coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("Answering time per question") +
  geom_line(aes(color = user, group = user), size = 2,
            data = ~ subset(., user %in% c(1L, 34L)))
```

[image: ggplot with lines for two users]

You can functionize it however you want. If you're using `dplyr`, you can use `dplyr::filter` instead of `subset` with no other change.

Also, I chose to `factor(user)`, since otherwise `ggplot2` tends to think its data is continuous (for `color=user`). You can choose to use or not use this, though you may need more wrangling to get it to be discrete.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach. Add a column to the data that indicates the highlighted users and map that variable to `geom_line`. Use `scale_color_discrete(na.translate = FALSE)` to color only the non-NA values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

pltSingleRespondent <- function(df, highlightUsers) {
  df %>% 
    mutate(User = factor(ifelse(user %in% highlightUsers, user, NA))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(question, time)) +
    geom_boxplot(fill = "orange") +
    geom_line(aes(color = User, group = User)) + 
    ggtitle("Answering time per question") +
    scale_color_discrete(na.translate = FALSE) + 
    coord_flip() + 
    theme_bw()
}
```

Using the example data from @r2evans

```
pltSingleRespondent(dat, c(1, 34))
```

[image]